# How shared_from_this() works in the derived class which inherits from base class inheriting from enabled_shared_from_this

Tags: c++, inheritance, shared-ptr

I am trying to know if my understanding is current regarding how the `shared_ptr` and `shared_from_this()` works and how memory allocation works.

Following are my classes:

```
class Component : public enable_shared_from_this <Component>
{

public:
    Component() :enable_shared_from_this(){}

};

class DerivedComponent : public Component
{
public:

    DerivedComponent()
    {}

    void tryDerivedShared()
    {
        auto sptr1 = shared_from_this();
        if (this == sptr1.get())
            std::cout << "Both have same starting address";

    }

private:
    std::vector<int> myVector;
};

int main()
{

    auto sptr = make_shared<DerivedComponent>();
    sptr->tryDerivedShared();

}
```

When I derived from a base class, what I understand is that the memory is allocated for the base first and then for the derived. So when I do `auto sptr1 = shared_from_this();` what happens is it returns the `shared_ptr` to the object of the base class Component. And since the base is a part of memory of the Derived class, the value of `this == sptr1.get()` is `true` because both of them returns the starting memory of the obj they point to. 
Basically the memory allocated is like |Base|Derived| and the `shared_from_this()` returns a `shared_ptr` pointing to only the object of Base i.e |Base| chunk of memory.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: sptr1.get() returns a `Component *`, `this` is a `DerivedComponent *`. The comparison operator can only compare pointers to the same type, and since `DerivedComponent *` can be casted to `Component *`, this is what happens, and you end up with the same pointer value. The equality comparison really has nothing to do with `shared_from_this()`.

Comment: I see your point. Thanks!

Comment: If you peek through the values of `this` and `sptr1.get()` they both are the same, that means that the sptr is shared_ptr on the Component obj created by the DerivedComponent and they share the same starting address. Am I right?

Comment: This is wrong: "When I derived from a base class, what I understand is that the memory is allocated for the base first and then for the derived". Any object has an exact size: The composed size of all data members (base to derived).

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to look at these classes as structures. Only your base class is empty, so that may not be the best example.

```
struct Component
{
};
```

When you derive, you actually add fields to a structure, but you may want to look at it this way:

```
struct DerivedComponent
{
    struct Component    component_;
    std::vector<int>    myVector;
};
```

Therefore, you are correct, when you allocate a `DerivedComponent`, the address of `Component` (or `&obj.component_`), are both the same and this is why you can `static_cast<>()` between the two.

Where it becomes much more complicated is when you derive from many classes, especially if using the `virtual` keyword. On the other hand, having virtual functions is not too complicated, it adds a virtual table pointer at the beginning, but as far as you're concerned that pointer is hidden.

The `enable_shared_from_this()` does not change that concept. It just adds a weak pointer to the `Component` structure. So the `Component` class looks more like this:

```
struct Component
{
    struct enable_shared_from_this   shared_;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> what I understand is that the memory is allocated for the base first and then for the derived.

No. Memory for whole object is acquired in one allocation. But additional allocations could be done during construction of data members. In case of make_shared, even additional memory required to support shared_ptr is allocated in that one allocation.

> So when I do auto sptr1 = shared_from_this(); what happens is it returns the shared_ptr to the object of the base class Component.

`shared_from_this()` returns an object of type `std::shared_ptr<Component>`, yes.

> And since the base is a part of memory of the Derived class, the value of this == sptr1.get() is true because both of them returns the starting memory of the obj they point to.

Not quite. This comparison is possible at all because `Derived*` can be implicitly converted to `Component*`. And since `sptr1` actually holds pointer to the very same object they do compare as equal.

> Basically the memory allocated is like |Base|Derived| and the shared_from_this() returns a shared_ptr pointing to only the object of Base i.e |Base| chunk of memory.

There is no such thing as 'chunk of memory tied to pointer'. Pointer is just an address in memory. Interpretation of what it is pointing to depends on type of the pointer. Your memory layout is almost correct, but there is no any kind of delimiter (in this case) between Base and Derived. Data members of Derived are occupying the memory immediately after data members of Base class. Mind you, we are talking about single inheritance here. Your `sptr1` can be used as pointer to `Component*` only because it has type `shared_ptr<Component>`. Since you are already in the method of `DerivedComponent` it is safe to use `std::static_pointer_cast<DerivedComponent>(sptr1)` to get `shared_ptr<Derived>`.

Since `shared_ptr` stores deleter of actual class it is created with, even if last reference held will be `shared_ptr<Component>`, it will call correct destructor, even if it's not virtual.